# Running jQuery on class added via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code to change an img src attribute from a light to a dark version after scrolling and adding a class `.scrolled` to the header:

```
 $j(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($j(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
         $j(".header").addClass("scrolled");
         $j(".header .logo img").attr("src", "http://[...]/logo_dark.svg");
     } else {
         $j(".header").removeClass("scrolled");
         $j(".header .logo img").attr("src", "http://[...]/logo_bright.svg");
     }
 });
```

Via css I am adding a white background to the header if the `.scrolled` class is present or if it is hovered:

```
 .header:hover, .header.scrolled {
     background: #fff
 }
```

Finally I also need to replace the logo with the dark version, if the header is hovered but the `.scrolled` class is not present since otherwise I will end up with the light logo being used on white background.
This is the jQuery I am trying but it will also trigger if the `.scrolled` class is present:

```
 $j(".header").not("[scrolled]").hover(function(){
     $j(".header .logo img").attr("src", "http://[...]/logo_dark.svg");
 }, function(){
     $j(".header .logo img").attr("src", "http://[...]/logo_bright.svg");
 });
```

How can I make sure this last jQuery only triggers if `.scrolled` has not been added to the header?

Comment: You might be able to use css background-image property and then change it via css at the same time you change the background colour.  (I've not tried this, so just a comment to see if it's viable).

Comment: Alternatively, you could include both images on the page then show/hide them via the css.  This would also have the advantage that the images will be pre-loaded so you won't get a delay as it loads the other image.

Comment: what is this? `.not("[scrolled]")` you mean `.not(".scrolled")`?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You are right, however this won't fix my problem

Comment: @loeffel change your selector to `$('.header:not(.scrolled)')`

Comment: @freedomn-m Your second suggestion is what I am going with for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's **.hasClass()** to first check if your header has the scrolled class, and only change the logo image src if so.

Editing to reply to comment:

Not to worry, just make sure you put the .hasClass() check around your hover function. Something like this:

```
if (!$j(".header").hasClass("scrolled")) {
    $j(".header").hover(function(){
        $j(".header .logo img").attr("src", "http://[...]/logo_dark.svg"); 
    }, function(){
         $j(".header .logo img").attr("src", "http://[...]/logo_bright.svg"); 
    }); 
}
```

I am new to stackoverflow, so many apologies if the formatting is terrible here.

Comment: But the src also needs to change on hover, not just if the scrolled class is present. However it musn't change on hover if the scrolled class is present.

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector from `$j(".header").not("[scrolled]")` to 
`$j('.header:not(.scrolled)')`

```
$j('.header:not(.scrolled)').hover(function(){
     $j(".header .logo img").attr("src", "http://[...]/logo_dark.svg");
 }, function(){
     $j(".header .logo img").attr("src", "http://[...]/logo_bright.svg");
 });
```

Comment: Both solutions suffer from the same problem as my approach: If hovering out of the header in scrolled state the logo img will change to the light version when it should not: http://codepen.io/vit6/pen/xqERea